# JavaFX 3D How to move node using relative positions

Tags: javafx, 3d

I am trying to automate some node's movements. 
I would like to move a node on top of another node but I am not able to achieve it using a generic method.

I.E. I wrote something like this:

```
    public Point3D getPosition(Node referenceNode, Node nodeToPlace) {
            Bounds refBounds = referenceNode.getBoundsInParent();
            double refX = refBounds.getMinX() + (refBounds.getWidth() / 2);
            double refY = refBounds.getMaxY() + nodeToPlace.getBoundsInParent().getHeight();
            double refZ = refBounds.getMinZ() + (refBounds.getDepth() / 2);

            double nodeToPlaceX = nodeToPlace.getBoundsInParent().getMinX() + 
                    (nodeToPlace.getBoundsInParent().getWidth()/2);
            double nodeToPlaceY = nodeToPlace.getBoundsInParent().getMinY() + 
                    (nodeToPlace.getBoundsInParent().getHeigth()/2);
            double nodeToPlaceZ = nodeToPlace.getBoundsInParent().getMinZ() + 
                    (nodeToPlace.getBoundsInParent().getDepth()/2);

            double translationX = refX - nodeToPlaceX;
            double translationY = refY - nodeToPlaceY;
            double translationZ = refZ - nodeToPlaceZ;

            nodeToPlace.getTransforms().add(new Translate(translationX,
            translationY, translationZ));
        }
```

What am I doing wrong? I suppose that I am not considering something of important but I can't figure it. I hope that someone can explain me the right way... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the first example seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37370840/230513), the example below uses a [`Timeline`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html) to animate the motion of `b1`, shaded `AQUA`, toward `b2`, tinted `CORAL`.

[image]

```
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Point3D;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.PerspectiveCamera;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.ScrollEvent;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.PhongMaterial;
import javafx.scene.shape.Box;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

/**
 @ @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37516327/230513
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37370840/230513
 */
public class TimelineMove extends Application {

    private static final double SIZE = 300;
    private final Content content = Content.create(SIZE);

    public void play() {
        content.animation.play();
    }

    private static final class Content {

        private static final Duration DURATION = Duration.seconds(4);
        private static final int W = 64;
        private final Group group = new Group();
        private final Rotate rx = new Rotate(0, Rotate.X_AXIS);
        private final Rotate ry = new Rotate(0, Rotate.Y_AXIS);
        private final Rotate rz = new Rotate(0, Rotate.Z_AXIS);
        private final Box b1;
        private final Box b2;
        private final Animation animation;

        private static Content create(double size) {
            Content c = new Content(size);
            c.group.getChildren().addAll(c.b1, c.b2);
            c.group.getTransforms().addAll(c.rz, c.ry, c.rx);
            c.rx.setAngle(12);
            c.ry.setAngle(-12);
            return c;
        }

        private Content(double size) {
            Point3D p1 = new Point3D(-size / 4, -size / 4, size / 4);
            b1 = createBox(Color.AQUA, p1);
            Point3D p2 = new Point3D(size / 4, size / 4, -size / 4);
            b2 = createBox(Color.CORAL, p2);
            animation = createTimeline(p1, p2);
        }

        private Box createBox(Color color, Point3D p) {
            Box b = new Box(W, W, W);
            b.setMaterial(new PhongMaterial(color));
            b.setTranslateX(p.getX());
            b.setTranslateY(p.getY());
            b.setTranslateZ(p.getZ());
            return b;
        }

        private Timeline createTimeline(Point3D p1, Point3D p2) {
            Timeline t = new Timeline();
            t.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
            t.setAutoReverse(true);
            KeyValue keyX = new KeyValue(b1.translateXProperty(), p2.getX() - p1.getX());
            KeyValue keyY = new KeyValue(b1.translateYProperty(), p2.getY() - p1.getY());
            KeyValue keyZ = new KeyValue(b1.translateZProperty(), p1.getZ() - p2.getZ());
            KeyFrame keyFrame = new KeyFrame(DURATION, keyX, keyY, keyZ);
            t.getKeyFrames().add(keyFrame);
            return t;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX 3D");
        Scene scene = new Scene(content.group, SIZE * 2, SIZE * 2, true);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        scene.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera(true);
        camera.setFarClip(SIZE * 6);
        camera.setTranslateZ(-2 * SIZE);
        scene.setCamera(camera);
        scene.setOnScroll((final ScrollEvent e) -> {
            camera.setTranslateZ(camera.getTranslateZ() + e.getDeltaY());
        });
        primaryStage.show();
        play();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks to be correct, *except* that you need to account for the transformations of the nodes' parents as well, in the general case that these two nodes don't have the same parent. (I assume `getBoundsInParent` returns the coordinates in the *parent's* frame of reference, not the world.)