# Collision Detection during PathTransition

Tags: animation, javafx

Im making a Galaga-like game and cant seem to get collision detection between a moving bullet and a rectangle (the rectangle is going to be an enemy but its just for testing). I was reading the documentation and found `interpolate(double frac)`.

> "While a Transition is running, this method is called in every frame.
>   The parameter defines the current position with the animation."

So this seems like it would work but I don't how to use it. I found a good method to actually detect collisions but I don't know how to make it work during an animation.

```
  Rectangle s1 = new Rectangle(200,5,25,25);
  Rectangle bullet = new Rectangle(12,15);

  PathTransition shot = new PathTransition(Duration.millis(8000),new 
  Line(ship.getX(),ship.getY(),ship.getX(),-15),bullet);

    shot.setCycleCount(1);
    shot.setRate(2);


    getChildren().add(bullet);

    shot.play();

///////////////////////



  if(bullet.getBoundsInParent().intersects(s1.getBoundsInParent()))
```

Comment: Check in a custom `Interpolator`, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39188588/230513).