# How do I get the x and y values of an objects position when it is moving in a timeline?

Tags: java, animation, javafx

I'm making a key shooter game in JavaFX where there are floating words moving around the screen. I want to shoot a "laser" (a elongated red rectangle) at the word once the user types the correct word. I need the x and y values of the word when the user types the correct word so I can make the rectangle travel to that position. How would I go about getting the key values?

Here is my timeline code:

```
final Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
timeline.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(wordTime),
        new KeyValue (word.getWordBox().translateXProperty(), rand.nextInt(100, 500))));
timeline.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(wordTime),
        new KeyValue (word.getWordBox().translateYProperty(), rand.nextInt(0, 150))));
```

wordTime is a value taken from user input that changes how long the words on the screen. word.getWordBox() is the word that moves around the screen. Please let me know if I need to restructure this question, give more detail, etc.

I tried to use

```
timeline.getKeyFrames().get(1).getValues()
```

to get the values but it just gave me the list of KeyValues which doesn't seem right. If this is right please let me know.

Comment: Can't you just get the bounds of the word directly? E.g. `word.getWordBox().getBoundsInParent()` (or whichever bounds are the most useful, if not those)?

Comment: @James_D Ah alright I think that should work. I'm new to this so I don't know all the method calls yet. Thank you!

Comment: Also consider an `Interpolator`, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39188588/230513).

Comment: @trashgod Interesting. I'll look more into this as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the most convenient value to get is the location of the word in its container ("parent node"). You can do this directly with

```
Bounds bounds = word.getWordBox().getBoundsInParent();
```

and then, e.g., do

```
double x = bounds.getCenterX();
double y = bounds.getCenterY();
```

etc.

Since the [`boundsInParent`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#boundsInParentProperty) accounts for any transforms applied to the node, this will include the current translation applied to it by the `timeline`.