# How to display, zoom cubes in 3D, in Java's Frame's panel?

Tags: java, swing, 3d

I need to be able to display a scene... :

1. Containing N cubes (with **precise** width, height and depth : each in the shape of "-/+[0|1|2].[0|1|...|9]+" - with **seven digits after the comma** : need a displaying with high-precision), with a given color (the same on all the faces of the cube)
2. I must be able to overlay a cube colored with white with another cube colored with red, of the same width, height and depth (of course, with same coordinates X, Y and Z) **and the latter must hide the first without any problem of Z-fighting**
3. I have coordinates X, Y and Z to place each cube in the scene
4. I must be able to rotate the entire scene (i.e. : each cube must rotate/move)
5. I must be able to zoom/unzoom in the scene, before or after having rotated the latter

***I don't want to use OpenGL, or something else than the standard Java's API.***

*For the moment, I just display pixels in a 2D `JFrame`'s panel (with the class `Graphics` and the overrided `paint()`). But my project makes me in need of switching with a 3D approach.* I would want to just change my use of `Graphics` and `paint()`, and to keep my `JFrame`'s panel.

**Is it possible? What class do you advice me?**

Comment: *"Is it possible?"* Sure, 'just' implement a 3D rendering API much in the same vein as already implemented in the API you've rejected using *"What class do you advice me?"* Do a class on 3D geometry for starters. I realise you meant the 'magic standard API class that does not exist', but seriously - you think 3D rendering is that easy? Start with simpler things.

Comment: There isn't any standard "3D scene" ? I must make use of OpenGL ?

Comment: *There isn't any standard "3D scene"* Short answer, no. Long answer, nope.

Answer (score 1):

Consider JavaFX, as shown in [*Getting Started with JavaFX 3D Graphics*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/graphics-tutorial/javafx-3d-graphics.htm). It uses the platform's available rendering pipeline internally, as discussed in [*JavaFX Architecture*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/jfx-architecture.htm). Several related examples are shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A230513%20%5Bjavafx%5D%203d). If you stay with Swing, you can embed JavaFX content using `JFXPanel`, seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31576647/230513). In particular, you can test overlap with this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37516327/230513).

[image]