# JavaFX 3D boxes overlapping each other

Tags: javafx

I am having a problem with *JavaFX 3D*, the problem is as follows:

When I turn my perspective camera around, the last added box (blue box) overlaps the first added box (red box), here is a screenshot:

[image]

can anyone tell me why is this happening? And is there a way to fix it? (the boxes are literally 2 box `classes` with a `width`, `height`, `depth`, `position` and `color`)

Minimal reproducible example since somebody asked for it:

```
Box box1 = new Box();
Box box2 = new Box();

box1.setWidth(300);
box2.setWidth(300);

box1.setHeight(300);
box2.setHeight(300);

box1.setDepth(300);
box2.setDepth(300);

box1.setTranslateX(300);
box2.setTranslateX(300);

box1.setTranslateY(300);
box2.setTranslateX(300);

Group root = new Group();

root.getChildren().addAll(box, box2);

PerspectiveCamera cam = new PerspectiveCamera();

Scene scene = new Scene(root);
scene.setCamera(camera);

stage.setScene(scene);
stage.show();
```

where stage is the stage inside public void start(Stage stage), JavaFX's default run method (any class that extends Application should implement it)

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: i dont know about 3d but look into your box2.translateX() you have not used box2.translateY().

Comment: A related example, shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37516327/230513), illustrates translation along _x_, _y_ and _y_ in a `Timeline`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

I used the following constructor:

`new Scene(root, WIDTH, HEIGHT, true, SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED);`

instead of:

`new Scene(root);`

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to add a subscene with the depth buffer enabled. See: https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/SubScene.html#%3Cinit%3E(javafx.scene.Parent,double,double,boolean,javafx.scene.SceneAntialiasing)