# How do I insert text into a shape in Javafx?

Tags: java, javafx

Using JavaFX I have created a simple rectangle object, and I want to be able to put a text object inside that rectangle, and for it to automatically stay aligned within the rectangle. The code I have to draw the rectangle is:

```
public static Scene createScene() {
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, Color.ALICEBLUE);

        Rectangle rectangle_red = new Rectangle();

        rectangle_red.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        rectangle_red.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        rectangle_red.setX(50);
        rectangle_red.setY(50);
        rectangle_red.setWidth(200);
        rectangle_red.setHeight(100);
        rectangle_red.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
        rectangle_red.setOnMousePressed(circleOnMousePressedEventHandler);
        rectangle_red.setOnMouseDragged(circleOnMouseDraggedEventHandler);        

        root.getChildren().add(rectangle_red);    

        return scene;
    }
```

The Handlers I have attached to the rectangle allow me to drag the rectangles anywhere in the window. How do I place text inside the rectangle such that it stays aligned as I drag the shape around the screen?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As illustrated in the last example seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37370840/230513), the [*Animation Basics*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/visual-effects-tutorial/basics.htm) example `TimelineEvents` does this by adding a `Circle` and some `Text` to a [`StackPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html), which centers its children by default. The stack can then be moved within an enclosing  `Group` as a unit.

```
final Circle circle = new Circle(…);
final Text text = new Text (…);
final StackPane stack = new StackPane();
stack.getChildren().addAll(circle, text);
…
stack.setLayoutX(30);
stack.setLayoutY(30);
```

[image]