# How to center a text in a rectangle in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, graphics

I am trying to draw a string exactly in the center of a rectangle using JavaFX GraphicsContext2D.
I don't want to use JavaFX components so please do not recommend them.

For example, I stroke a rectangle with attributes: x = 10, y = 10, width = 100, height = 100. Now I want to stroke a text in a way that it comes exactly in the center(horizontally and vertically) of the rectangle. How can I do it?

Comment: Does calling `setTextAlign(TextAlignment.CENTER);` and `setTextBaseline(VPos.CENTER)`, and then positioning the text at the Center of the rectangle (55,55) not work?

Comment: For context, also see the related question: [how to put a text into a circle object to display it from circle's center?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17437411/how-to-put-a-text-into-a-circle-object-to-display-it-from-circles-center), which discusses the [text bounds type](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/text/Text.html#boundsTypeProperty).  Note that text bounds type can't be set for canvas as far as I can tell and is more applicable when using layout managers in the scene graph, so this answer is probably not directly applicable to your situation.

Comment: A related example is examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46998782/230513). You may have a good reasons to confine rendering to a single `Node` of type `Canvas`; it's as close to the host platform's rendering pipeline as your likely to get, but you have to manage all the geometry yourself. Don't hesitate to re-examine the decision as your understanding  evolves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @James_D [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68414793/how-to-center-a-text-in-a-rectangle-in-javafx/68422884#comment120911679_68414793), you can use the [`GraphicsContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/GraphicsContext.html) methods `setTextAlign()` and `setTextBaseline()` to center the `fillText()` in an arbitrary `Rectangle`. Starting from this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53785468/230513), I added the following lines in the `tooltips` loop in order to produce the image shown:

```
gc.setTextAlign(TextAlignment.CENTER);
gc.setTextBaseline(VPos.CENTER);
gc.setFill(Color.BLACK);
gc.fillText(color.toString(),
    bounds.getX() + bounds.getWidth() / 2,
    bounds.getY() + bounds.getHeight() / 2);
```

[image]