# Add multiple path transitions to an image

Tags: java, animation, javafx, path, transition

I want to add different path transitions to an image. This is what i have done so far. What can i do?

```
        QuadCurve ll= new QuadCurve(250,180,475,0,700,180);

        Line c912 = new Line(700,180,250,180);
        PathTransition ty= new PathTransition();
        ty.setNode(iv123);
        ty.setDuration(Duration.seconds(10));
        ty.setPath(ll);
        ty.setOnFinished(e -> {
            ty.setNode(c912);
            ty.play();

        });
        ty.play();
```

Comment: Not sure what the desired result is, but maybe using a `Path` containing `PathElement`s for every part of the path is what you're looking for?

Comment: @fabian how can i link an `ImageView` obeject with `Path`

Comment: `pathTransition.setPath(path)`

Comment: @fabian still doesnt help

Comment: Among the examples are cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37370840/230513); the second one illustrates @fabian's suggestion of `setPath()`.

Comment: It's hard to determine what exactly you're trying to achieve from those 3 sentences in the question. (3 people have already voted to close this question, so I'm not the only one who has a hard time determining the desired outcome.) A few sentences describing which nodes you expect to do which movements would certainly help. If you think it helps conveying the info you could also include a image in your post visualizing the desired movements via arrows and the like...