# JavaFX collision with multiple threads

Tags: javafx, collision

So I am making Plants vs Zombies in JavaFX. The best I could come up with for moving zombies and mowers etc was to execute each of them as thread. Now the issue is when do you check for collisions ? I tried using a while loop and it took forever and program just stopped. What should be condition for checking collision. Here is how I am doing:

```
while (true){
            for (Zombie z : zombies[0]){
                Shape a = Shape.intersect(z,mowers[0]);
                if (a != null){
                    mowers[0].takeHit(1);
                    z.takeHit(100);
                }
            }
        }
```

Issue is that zombie takes atleast 20 seconds to come till mower.
**How do I use this loop more efficiently. As in how to replace the while loop more efficiently ?**

For further reference, this is how zombie is moving

```
Thread.sleep(toStart*1000);
TranslateTransition translate = new TranslateTransition();
z.t = translate;
translate.setToX(-(1650+155));
translate.setDuration(Duration.seconds(30));
translate.setNode(z);
translate.play();
z.countdown.await();
node.remove.acquire();
node.root.getChildren().remove(z);
node.remove.release();
```

Comment: One approach is show [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39188588/230513).

Comment: Creating a seperate thread for every object on the screen is a terribly idea. You'll end up with an excessive amount of threads all fighting for processor time slowing down everything and you've also created yourself a nightmare when trying to synchronize everything. If the synchronisation is done properly, your threads will also need to spend much time waiting for other threads to release locks on data. I see 2 options here: a) update the gui stepwise. You could e.g. use `Timeline` which would allow you to avoid synchronisation entirely, since none of your code runs concurrently.

Comment: b) Create a single thread doing all the updates on a set of data seperate from the gui and regularly doing updates to the gui using `Platform.runLater`. This requires you to ensure the update rate is limited though. Otherwise all the runnables will slow down the gui updates to the point where the gui is effectively frozen.

Comment: Note that the approach I [cited above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59101153/javafx-collision-with-multiple-threads#comment104436344_59101153) and @fabian's `Timeline` suggestion do the waiting in the background, invoking `Platform.runLater()` as required. The last example examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37370840/230513) mixes `AnimationTimer` and `Timeline`.