# How to attach a 3D object to another 3D object JavaFX?

Tags: object, javafx, 3d, rotation

Is there any way to attach a 3D object to another 3D object? What I mean by that is if the two objects moved as though they are one? If I rotate one, then the other rotates along with it? Any help or guidance is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: These [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37075261/230513) illustrate various combinations using [`javafx.scene.Group`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Group.html).

Comment: @trashgod awesome thanks dude!! ill definitely check this out.