# JavaFX 3D set rotation to "absolute position"

Tags: javafx, rotation

I am playing around, trying to make a little JavaFX application to visualize data received via the serial port from an arduino-based board and some sensors.

After adding some live-updating LineGraphs, I am currently trying to display the roll, pitch and yaw values received from the micro-controller, by rotating a simple box-element.

I have one thread calling a function every *x* ms, which stores the incoming data into an `ObservableList` with an `changeListener` and calls the controller based function to update/rotate the orientation of the box.

Since the calculation of the angles is allready done on the micro-controller, I would like to rotate the box to the received absolute orientation.

From what I've understand so far, I can't simply rotate from any previous orientation to a new absolute one, but only change the orientation relatively to the previous one.

I came up with the following idea to just subtract the last roll/pitch/yaw values from the penultimate one of the observableList.

```
Data dataTmp = observableList.get(observableList.size()-2);
Data dataTmp2 = observableList.get(observableList.size()-1);

newRoll = dataTmp2.getRoll() - dataTmp.getRoll();
newPitch = dataTmp2.getPitch() - dataTmp.getPitch();
newYaw = dataTmp2.getYaw() - dataTmp.getYaw();

Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        controller.setToPosition(newRoll, newPitch, newYaw);
    }
});

//...
```

This only works out to a certain extent. I still want to rotate to the absolute position received from the micro-controller.

So my question is this: Is there a way to reset the orientation of the box to e.g. 0, 0, 0 from where I could rotate to my new absolute orientation? Simply removing the box and adding a new one did not work out at all.

```
group.getChildren().remove(box);
box = new Box(300,50,300);
group.getChildren().add(box);
```

Thank you in advance for any ideas or even solutions. If you need more information or code snippets let me know.

Comment: The book [JavaFX 9 By Example](http://www.apress.com/9781484219607) has an example exactly on this. You can get the source code [here](https://github.com/Apress/javafx-9-by-example/raw/master/JFXBE_JPereda.zip). Anyway, you haven't posted how you set the box rotation (`controller::setToPosition`), so it is hard to help you on that.

Comment: Among the example seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37075261/230513), several display three orthogonal axes that transform as a `Group`.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37685167/230513), an `onMouseMoved` handler rotates the red `Box` around the *x* and *y* axes as the mouse moves. The following `onKeyPressed` handler restores the red `Box` to its original position when the <kbd>Z</kbd> key is pressed. Each handler uses the `setAngle()` method of the [`Rotate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/transform/Rotate.html) class.

```
scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
    if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.Z) {
        content.rx.setAngle(0);
        content.ry.setAngle(0);
        content.rz.setAngle(0);
    }
});
```

Similarly, your `setToPosition()` implementation can invoke `setAngle()` to establish the new roll, pitch and yaw values.

Before:

[image: before]

After:

[image: after]

More subtly, verify that you synchronize access to any data shared between your data acquisition thread and the [JavaFX application thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19755031/230513). This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44056730/230513) illustrates a `Task<Canvas>`, while your application might instead implement a `Task<Point3D>`, where a `Point3D` holds the roll, pitch and yaw values.