# How to position a Camera so a Node fully fills a scene JavaFX 3D

Tags: java, javafx, 3d, javafx-8

I am looking to initially position my Scene's Camera Z-Distance away from a Group in order to make it so that the bounds of this Group will fit into the scene and be as big as possible.  The group  consisting of a flat plane with some boxes extending towards the camera (think of a bookshelf where the back of the bookshelf is Z=0).  The Group and Scene will be varying widths and heights i.e., initial size of bookshelf 100w,50h, scene 1000w 400h.

I initially thought that I could attempt to find the distance using `tan(FoV) = sceneHeight / distance;` but that didn't work at all.  I have looked at a few examples that approach it that way as well, but to no avail have I got this working.  I am wondering if I would have to work with the object's initial height i.e., 300, and compare it to the height I am looking for i.e., 1920.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You may get some ideas from these related [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37075261/230513) that dolly the camera along _Z_ as a function of `SIZE`, which also serves as a common dimension in the scene.

Comment: @trashgod thank you for the link.  I don't think that the examples fit what I am looking for, is there one I should look at, I tried the last one.  I am trying to have an object be fullscreen when my program open, while the object and the scene will have different widths and heights.  Thank you for your help thus far.

Comment: Each example has a `setOnScroll()` handler that might let you determine a suitable _Z_ value empirically, maybe twice the larger object dimension; zoom (scroll) to see the effect off near and far clipping; in any case, give the user intuitive mouse controls, nearby FX controls, and easy access to help.